# Difference between 'require bundler' and 'require bundler/setup'

Tags: ruby, bundler

When I use

```
require 'bundler/setup'
```

i get `Bundler.with_clean_env` is not supported.

But when I change this to

```
require 'bundler'
```

It supports `Bundler.with_clean_env`. The confusion that rises here is what is the difference between requiring `'bundler'` and `'bundler/setup'`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When referring to gems, `require 'foo'` would require the `foo.rb` [file](https://github.com/bundler/bundler/blob/master/lib/bundler.rb) that is located in the gem's `lib` directory. That file usually has the same name as the gem and is responsible for requiring all other necessary files for the gem to function.

When you do `require 'foo/bar'`, you search for `lib/foo/bar.rb`. In other words, you require only a specific [file](https://github.com/bundler/bundler/blob/master/lib/bundler/setup.rb) from that gem and not the whole thing.

---

The `bundler/setup` is responsible for loading all gems described in your Gemfile. `Bundler.with_clean_env` is a completely different functionality, [defined](https://github.com/bundler/bundler/blob/42b1e1b9c3f4b3a45cd27214ef656911951b4d94/lib/bundler.rb#L285) in the gem's main file.

Answer (score 1):

Gemfiles can include [groups](http://bundler.io/v1.14/groups.html) like `:test` or `:development`.

- `require 'bundler/setup'` includes all groups from your Gemfile.
- `require 'bundler'` on the other hand lets you specify (via `Bundler.setup`) which groups to include.

From the [documentation](http://bundler.io/v1.14/bundler_setup.html):

> Configure the load path so all dependencies in your Gemfile can be required
>
> ```
> require 'rubygems'
> require 'bundler/setup'
> require 'nokogiri'
> ```
>
> Only add gems from specified groups to the load path. If you want the gems in the default group, make sure to include it
>
> ```
> require 'rubygems'
> require 'bundler'
> Bundler.setup(:default, :ci)
> require 'nokogiri'
> ```