# Requiring 'bundler' or 'bundler/setup'?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundler

What's the difference between requiring either of these 2? Will `require bundler` give me any additional functionality that `bundler/setup` won't? I've seen someone asking a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42294482/difference-between-require-bundler-and-require-bundler-setup) but the answer was extremely generic, like what does `require gem` vs `require gem/file` is, not necessarily in Bundler context.

Comment: I think that this may help you: http://www.brianstorti.com/understanding-bundler-setup-process/

Comment: I've added a more specific answer to the other question and will close this one as a duplicate.